# How to get nid of a managed file?

Tags: 7, files

in hook_file_download there is just a parameter named *uri*. How can I get nid of the node that contains the file in uri?

For exmpale I have a file field in my content type.I create a node and add some files to file field. Now when this file is going to be downloaded, in hook_file_download I want to get nid of the file.How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an file attached through a file or image field, you can instead implement [hook_file_download_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--file--file.api.php/function/hook_file_download_access/7), which gives you the $field, $entity_type and $entity to which the file belongs.